# Как отключить "повторную отправку формы" при использовании AJAX?

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Есть форма

```
    <form action="" id='cbhandler' method='POST' class="callback-popup-form">
        <input type="text" name='phone' class="main-input callback-input" placeholder="Телефон" id="phone">
        <button  class="callback-submit login-popup-submit">Перезвонить</button>
    </form>
```

Отсылается аяксом:

```
  $('#cbhandler').submit(function(e){
  event.preventDefault();
  var $form = $(this);
  var serializedData = $form.serialize();

 $.ajax({
     url: '/cbhandler.php',
     method: 'POST',
     data: serializedData,
     success: function(txt){

         return false;
     },
     error: function(txt){
         return false;


     }
 });
});
```

Обрабатывается пхп-файлом:

```
if(isset($_POST)){ $tel = isset($_POST['phone']) ? $_POST['phone'] : 'ewqqw';
if(preg_match("/\+380\([0-9]{2}\) [0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}/", $tel)){
    mail('email@gmail.com', 'MirBeer: Заказ обратного звонка', 'Клиент:  '.$tel.'');
}}
```

Данные отправляются, НО при обновлении страницы с формой выскакивает предложение об повторной отправке формы.

**Примечания**:
**Изначально форма скрыта**, она появляется `(fadeIn())` после клика по некоторому полю.

Comment: `e.preventDefault` а не `event`, ну или параметр переименуйте. но сделайте одинаково

Comment: 1. Делайте редирект, например, на /?success 2. Отправляйте аяксом, очищайте все поля, скрывайте снова форму, выводите сообщение об успешной отправке. В смысле либо то, либо другое используется.

Answer (score 2):

У Вас тут ошибка

```
$('#cbhandler').submit(function(e){
  event.preventDefault();
```

Вы передаете в функцию `e`, но прекращаете действие через `event`, нужно заменить `event на e` или `e на event`

Answer (score -2):

Вы "слушаете" событие **`submit`** на форме и "через него" отправляете данные. А событие **`submit`** для **`html`** формы является событием по умолчанию, т.е. таким, которое запускает стандартное поведение элемента. Для формы это переход по ссылке в атрибуте **`action`** с отправкой туда данных своих инпутов и прочих текстарэев методом, указанным в атрибуте **`method`**

Но ведь вы используете **`ajax`**, а значит стандартное поведение формы необходимо приглушить,

```
$('#cbhandler').submit(function() {
    event.preventDefault(); //
    ...
```

а лучше не  вызывать вовсе:

```
$('ID_батона_в_формы').click(function() {
    ...
// клик на кнопке также соберёт данные формы и отправит, но перехода не произойдёт
```

Comment: `$.preventDefault()`? вы точно что-то путаете Кирилл

Comment: @ferrari бывает